# data structure to contain max 100 number and easy to find min number

Tags: c++

I need to save id's between (0,100) in some data structures, there won't be more than 100 id's and I need easy and fast way to find the minimum number in the data structure and easy way to insert and delete a certain number in the data structure, for example, if it would be list,
So `list.append(1)`, `list.append(2)`, `list.append(99)`, `list.remove(2) a = list.min()`.
I am a bit new to c++, and not sure what data structure support it efficiently.

Comment: I'd just use a vector and `std::min_element`

Comment: Potentially, `std::set`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `std::set`, which is typically implemented as a binary search tree.

Its `insert()`, `erase()` and `find()` methods are logarithmic in size, but can do better if a hint is given. The logarithmic complexity is referred to the the Java TreeSet.

I think you should be interested in `std::lower_bound`, which returns an iterator to the lower bound, and in `std::upper_bound`, which returns an iterator to the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

For this request a special data structure exist: the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) :)

```
std::vector<std::uint32_t> vInts = { 25,10,35,30,5,15 };

//converts to min heap
std::make_heap(vInts.begin(), vInts.end(), std::greater<std::uint32_t>());

//5
std::cout << *vInts.begin() << std::endl;

//pop 5
std::pop_heap(vInts.begin(), vInts.end(), std::greater<std::uint32_t>());
vInts.pop_back();
std::cout << *vInts.begin() << std::endl; //10

//pop 10
std::pop_heap(vInts.begin(), vInts.end(), std::greater<std::uint32_t>());
vInts.pop_back();

//push 20. min will be still 15
vInts.push_back(20);
std::push_heap(vInts.begin(), vInts.end(), std::greater<std::uint32_t>());
std::cout << *vInts.begin() << std::endl; //15

//pop 15
std::pop_heap(vInts.begin(), vInts.end(), std::greater<std::uint32_t>());
vInts.pop_back();

std::cout << *vInts.begin() << std::endl; //20
```

Comment: OP can remove random number too, not only pop minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
std::vector<int> container;
container.reserve(100);
// ... put stuff in container ...
const auto min_elem =
    std::min_element(container.begin(), 
        container.end());
```